# IBM Mobile First Server 7.1 Installation - Unable to open Application Center Console

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-appcenter

I'm trying to install IBM Mobile First Server, in the process of installation I selected **Install Application Center** to install. But when I'm trying access that application center console I'm getting an error:

> Error 404: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.exception.NoTargetForURIException: No target servlet configured for uri: /appcenterconsole

I'm hitting the URL `http://localhost:9080/appcenterconsole`.

I'm following this doc

https://www01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHSCD_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/install_config/t_ov_server_install.html

Can anyone help me with this? I'm facing this issues from last two days.

Comment: Looks like you're following the wrong documentation? Make sure to follow this: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/appcenter/c_installation_manager.html - if the failure continues to occur, provide the messages.log file.

Comment: Also note that there is no relation between MobileFirst Server and AppCenter - two different servers.

Comment: Do you want me install the Application Center separately, I mean not including in Mobile First Server

Comment: I am just saying these are two separate servers and you should not confuse the two in your question.

Comment: Actually my intention is, I want to maintain my Mobile First Studio Enterprise Edition  in my machine and Mobile First Server Enterprise Edition on another VM. So Can you please suggest me which procedure I should follow.

Comment: Again, what does this has to do with MobileFirst AppCenter? It is *a different server*(!). Please, make sure to again follow the instructions and provide what I have requested. Try.

Comment: The error means that the application did not start. Do you have errors in the liberty log file ? (usr/servers/<serername>/logs/message.log)

Comment: @VenkateshVoona, Waiting to hear your reply.

Comment: Sorry @Idan for the late reply, because I'm unable to connect my VM due to some network issue. Here is my log file https://www.dropbox.com/s/o8e0911z91azozf/messages.log?dl=0

Comment: You need to talk with whomever is controlling your VM machine. The log file clearly states that port 9080 is already taken. You need to understand what in your network setup has taken it.

Comment: I was tested in VM , like I stopped my server which I was created in Liberty  Core and I gave command netstat in cmd , there I didn't found 9080 port number, again I started my server and I checked this port number now found 9080 that means no other application using this 9080 port.

Comment: Then open server.xml and use a different port.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to install mobile first server using Installation Manager. I am not able to find Installation Manager repository link for IBM Mobile first server. Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the AppCenter's ports in the server.xml file of the underlying application server that you have deployed it to.

Search for 9080 as the HTTP port and 9443 as the HTTPS port. Change these values o port numbers that are not taken.

Comment: Still having the same error after changing my server.xml file. Have a look into my server.xml and message.log files in cloudshare https://www.dropbox.com/sh/n336gzpvp21vt1g/AADrduSOP9cHUWERhgBmAOHca?dl=0

Comment: Did you even read the log? It says the exact same error about port 9080. Please read the log.

Comment: I changed the port number into 9081 in server.xml, but it showing same error in log. I don't know why. could you please check in my server.xml file .

Comment: Did you restart the server/VM?

Comment: No. I will restart it now.

Comment: I restarted my VM and server , still the same error is showing in log file which is created newly.

Comment: Something is very wrong with your VM. Talk with your IT administrator.

Comment: Thanks @ Idan and  @Didier Vidal, Now its working for me.